# Re-initialize Dynamic Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic

I have a large range of cells (about 30,000 Rows, 60 columns) that overflows when I use the Range.Value function.  This seems to happen because the memory managed array created by the Range.Value function isn't large enough.  If I declare an array then it works just fine.  So I need a Dynamic Array variable that I can set equal to the Range.Value, transfer the data somewhere else on the sheet and then reinitialize it for the next large range.  I can't for the life of me, find information on how to reinitialize a Dynamic Array.

If I use `Erase myArray` then it seems I can't assign values to the variable anymore, but I can't `Dim` the array again either.  If I `Redim`, i'll have to create a lot of complicated functions to manually find the size of my array.  What is the trick here?

Comment: I think I am missing something here, but 'Redim' should simply work and it is the best solution here. Can you give an example for why it complicates your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just override an existing array with the new range values.

If there are less rows/columns within the new range, than what was previously assigned to the array, it will still erase all data that was previously in the array - only the new range values are assigned to the array.

```
Sub populateArray()

    Dim arrValues() As Variant

    arrValues = Range("B1:B6")
    arrValues = Range("A1:A4")

End Sub
```

`arrValues` will only contain 4 rows of data after the `Range("A1:A4")` is assigned, even though there was previously 6 rows of data assigned `Range("B1:B6")`.